# Contents of /usr/bin from subprocess.Popen different than from terminal

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am attempting to create an application for changing the wallpaper with gnome-builder. I've chosen to create this application in Python, and figured that I could do this using `subprocess.Popen(["hsetroot", ...])` however every time I try this I get the following error:`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hsetroot'`.

This confused me because I know that hsetroot is installed and running the same command from the terminal works. I decided to do some investigating, and listed the contents of /usr/bin from the terminal using `ls /usr/bin`. Among the list I found hsetroot. I did the same thing in the Python script with `subprocess.Popen(["ls", "/usr/bin"])` and upon checking the list of programs, hsetroot was not there.

Why is hsetroot seemingly gone when I try running it from a Python script with `subprocess.Popen()` and how do I fix this? I apologize if it is obvious, I have been searching for the answer for over a day now and I am completely stumped.

On `Debian GNU/Linux 11`, I am running the application using GNOME Builder's built-in run button. GNOME Builder was installed via `apt-get install gnome-builder`. From there I created a new python project using the "GNOME Application" template. In the project I am attempting to use `subprocess.Popen()` from `src/window.py`.

Comment: How exactly are you running this application?  Does it run inside a container or a chroot jail?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am honestly not sure. I am testing the application using GNOME Builder's built-in run button.

Comment: Filesystem namespaces are a thing. Specifically, they're a thing that are generally leveraged for security reasons, to prevent processes from getting into things that they shouldn't.

Comment: Anyhow, it's not a problem with your Python code, or a problem you can fix by _changing_ your Python code either. This is an execution-environment issue: you want to change the context that _the thing that runs your Python code_ lives in. As in, this question isn't currently asked in a way that makes it answerable.

Comment: By the way, have you considered running your Python program _from the terminal_?

Comment: Anyhow -- to be answerable, we need a [mre] -- the shortest possible set of instructions that let us produce this problem ourselves. How you installed GNOME Builder is a critical detail, for example; if it was installed through a packaging system that builds in sandbox-based security, well, there you are

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, I see, thank you for the clarification. I have edited the question to include steps for reproducing.

Comment: Which distro (and version of same)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Debian GNU/Linux 11, edited question again to include that.

Comment: Digging in a little, it looks like the GNOME Builder team's preferred distribution mechanism is Flatpak, which _definitely_ does sandboxing. I don't know how installation with apt-get works without actually setting up a VM running your distro and looking at it, and that's probably not a thing I have time for right now.

Comment: (it also clearly supports alternate sysroots, and if that's enabled, it's another way to get the behavior you're seeing)

Comment: Anyhow, personally, in your shoes, I'd just stop using Builder. But granted, I'm saying that as someone who built Python GUI apps for years before it ever existed (PyGTK has been around for a while; it existed when I was in college, and that was 20 years ago now).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll probably attempt to stop using Builder. Thank you for your help, I'm pretty new to most things Linux and I'm probably diving right into the deep end. It's been fun though!